# Spring MVC Test failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test, spring-ioc

I am trying to run a Spring MVC Test but keep getting this exception.

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

The exception is occuring because the autowired dependency,

```
    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;
```

is not getting injected in the test (works fine outside of the test).

Can anyone help me with this. Here is my code:

//AccountControllerITest Class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MockServletContext.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AccountControllerITest {

private MockMvc mvc;

ObjectMapper om;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new AccountController()).build();
}

@Test
public void getAccounts() throws Exception {
    MvcResult mvcResult =     mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/accounts"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
}    
}
```

}

//AccountController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/accounts")
public class AccountController {

@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Set<AccountInfo>> getAccounts(@RequestParam(value = "firstName", required = false) String firstName,
                                                    @RequestParam(value = "surName", required = false)  String surName) {
    Set<AccountInfo> accounts = accountService.getAccounts(firstName, surName);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(accounts, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use constructor injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using standalone setup: `mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new AccountController()).build();`. If you create controller via `new AccountController()`, Spring doesn't have a chance to inject `accountService` as it doesn't control instances creation and wiring.

You have two options:

1. Switch your test to unit test and do not use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` nor `MockServletContext` at
   all. You can use `@InjectMocks` to inject private `accountService`:

   ```
   public class AccountControllerITest {

       private MockMvc mvc;

       ObjectMapper om;

       @Mock
       private AccountController accountController = new AccountController();

       @InjectMocks
       private AccountService accountService = new Mockito.mock(AccountService.class);

       @Before
       public void setUp() throws Exception {
           mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
       }
   ```

   There is also enhancement you can apply to your controller. Replace field injection with constructor injection and you can pass `accountService` to controller via constructor in test. This way you don't need to use `@InjectMocks` at all.
2. Use webAppContext setup:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

   @BeforeMethod
   public void init() {
       mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
   }
   ```

Comment: @Ikmac- thanks for your reply. Could you explain further what the issue is please as I don't understand. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I went with option 2. I understand now what the issue was. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your test to inject your autowired properties. See the following code block:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class AccountControllerITest {

    // ... your test code

    @Configuration
    public static class YourConfiguration {

        @Bean
        AccountService accountService() {
            // init and return your AccountService
        }
    }
}
```

You can init your `AccountService` with [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito).

Comment: This doesn't help as he is mixing integration with unit test.